# how to send a form using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, forms

what is wrong in my function can somebody please fix it... or tell me any better solution

```
$("#temp_result").load("ef_StdInfo_todb.php", [{name:'std_first_name', value:'somevalue'},{name:'std_last_name', value:'somevalue'}]
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error:

```
$("#temp_result").load("ef_StdInfo_todb.php", [{name:'std_first_name', value:'somevalue'},{name:'std_last_name', value:'somevalue'}]);
```

You are missing ");" at the end.

Comment: But that is still not working .. this this the proper way to use a load function  in jquery

Comment: Please specify which part is not working? Are you receiving an error of sorts? What are you expecting to happen that does not? The only other thing I can think is your data should not be an array, but instead an object. ( { data : [{name:'std_first_name', value:'somevalue'},{name:'std_last_name', value:'somevalue'}]} ); Even then, load() is a get request by default. You may want to use post to pass more complicated data like an array.

Comment: Actually i'm getting data when i use `
$("#temp_result").load("ef_StdInfo_todb.php", {'std_first_name':'firstname', 'std_middle_name':'middlename'})
`
but when i use a function to find all the objects from page and that returns the same string... i.e.
`
$("#temp_result").load("ef_StdInfo_todb.php", {formValues()})
`
then this doesn't work... no error even.. i'm using chrome.. and there is no any error in INSPECT ELEMENT as well

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your problem. I would suggest using firefox and installing firebug and using the console to monitor your ajax requests and see if you're getting the response you expect from the server. If you're calling load() and your callback does not execute, it is possible the request was not successful due to an error. If you get can confirm what is sent / received and you're still having a problem, add some more examples to your question.